# Delphi 10.4 with MacOS - lowest version of MacOS and XCode possible?

Tags: ios, macos, delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 10.4.

Due to Mac hardware constraint, I can only install MacOS High Sierra.  What XCode version do I need to install to allow Delphi to compile iOS apps? XCode is a multi-GB download so I'm hoping I can get some tips on versions without pulling my hair out with different XCode/SDK versions.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the 10.4 requirements:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Installation_Notes

macOS 10.13, 10.14, 10.15, Xcode 10.12 or later. I suggest not using Xcode 12 though (just yet), and you won't be able to install that on High Sierra anyway.

If you wish to deploy iOS apps to the App Store, you're going to be out of luck, because they require you target the iOS 13 SDK, which requires Xcode 11 or later, which requires macOS 10.14.3 or later.

Bottom line: if you want to target the App Store, stay close to current with everything. If you're considering Android and its Play Store, the same will apply

Comment: hi Dave, thanks for the reply.  Looks like I've to get some hardware after I've done initial testing on High Sierra.  Is there a reason not to use XCode 12 yet?  is it compatibility with Delphi 10.4 issues?

Comment: It is possible to use Xcode 12 with Delphi, as long as you’ve already imported iOS 13.5 (or lower) SDK, including adding the Metal and MetalKit frameworks, and any others you might need. Otherwise, avoid it for now

Comment: I have a related problem with Delphi not being able to find ACTOOL when compiling.  If you know the answer, this is the thread.  Thanks!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179455/problem-compiling-ios-app-with-delphi-10-4-and-xcode-10-1-could-not-find-usr

Answer (score 2):

Reading the Embarcadero [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites):

*For iOS application development, you need to have installed on the Mac:
iOS 10.3.x SDK, iOS 11 SDK, iOS 12 SDK, or iOS 13 SDK
Xcode 8, Xcode 9, or Xcode 10.*

Comment: @PeterW. You should mark the answer as good answer if it is. If you need help about something not covered by your initial question, feel free to open a new question with appropriate subject.

Comment: ok, noted. I clicked the up arrow for both. realised I should click the Check mark as well. thanks for reminder.

Comment: Your welcome. By the way, you can mark only one as the correct answer. Please verify that you selected the one you find most correct and useful for the next one reading the question.